# Monitor network connection, auto response

Tags: windows, networking

Requests originating from a program.  I've managed to track the particular requests via wireshark, they are HTTP requests.

This is the image below on wireshark.

[image]

This is the request it's a POST

```
POST http://site.com/?login=null HTTP/1.0
Host: 55.32.33.11
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 16
Cache-Control: no-cache

//password
```

This is the response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 09 Nov 2012 13:06:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Content-Length: 12
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

unauthorized
```

The request itself is a bit confusing, I would appreciate a clarification.

Surprisingly as this is A HTTP request, it doesn't show up on fiddler. 
So, how can I make a response to this? Is it possible via wireshark?
Make the response go from unauthorized to authorized?

What tools are there to do this?

I have also tried editing the `windows host file` but it just ignores it.

Thanks

==========================================

Edit, how can I direct all requests to a particular IP to my localhost? 127.0.0.1

Bounty added

Comment: So you want to make the program think it was authenticated at the server when it actually wasn't?  In what way did you edit the HOSTS file in attempts to facilitate what you're asking for (changing the response)?  What exactly do you find confusing about the POST?

Comment: @techie007 Thank you immensely for your response.

I put this rule in my hosts file 

`127.0.0.1 webpay.site.com`
So the request gets sent to my localhost, where I return a simple "authorized". But it seems to ignore the new rule and proceeds to wait from a response from the server itself.

Comment: I find it confusing because it wasn't showing up in fiddler.

Answer (score 2):

In your place, I would try to trace the origin of that request and uninstall that product.

Use a tracer such as [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx), or try some of the alternatives [found here](http://alternativeto.net/software/tcpviews/).
As regarding Fiddler, try installing the latest Fiddler version 4.

If this is happening from the browser, then check your add-ons.

Comment: The url that doesn't inspire much confidence is put in an image to avoid google text caching. Please edit.

Comment: Not understood. Do you mean this url is legit?

Comment: Is this coming from a browser? If so you could maybe use Greasemonkey to modify in the html the address to localhost before it's sent.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question, which seems to be about what you're trying to do.

"Redirect request to an external IP to localhost (emulate a server)"

https://serverfault.com/questions/171850/redirect-request-to-an-external-ip-to-localhost-emulate-a-server

The "route add" answer looks like a better, uh, route.